# Using sklearn's GridSearchCV in python 3.7

Tags: scikit-learn, pickle

I am working on a project written in Python 3.7. I would like to use sklearn's GridSearchCV. This is an example:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV

param_grid = {
    "max_depth": [1,2,3],
    "min_samples_split": [1,2,3],
    "min_samples_leaf": [1,2,3]}
clf = DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=42, criterion="gini")
grid_cv = GridSearchCV(clf, param_grid, scoring="roc_auc", n_jobs=-1, cv=3).fit(X_train, y_train)
```

However, when I run the script above I get a pickle error:
`ValueError: unsupported pickle protocol: 5`

I have pickle5 installed in my environment. What should I do to make this work?